# Why does agent.(parameter) only work in certain code blocks?

Tags: anylogic

I'm making a model where a bus picks up passengers at one stop and drops them off at the other. The Agent is a bus with an int parameter called "capacity". I just used "agent.capacity" in selectOutput1 block and it worked just fine. When I try to use this in the moveTo block, I get the error "Agent cannot be resolved to a variable". So, why does "agent.capacity" work in some places and not others? Also, how do I deal with this issue? TIA

Answer (score 0):

There's a little bulb to the left of each edit box... this bulb will tell what you can use (hover over it).
[image: move To]

In this image you see that on Delay time you can use agent as a variable, and you can also use self as a variable (which represents the block itself)

but in capacity... that bulb is not there... this means that you CANT use agent.

This is the way of knowing if you can use it or not.

Comment: Do check my blog post on the "magic lightbulb" for more info :-) https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling